# How can I make a submit button using html for several form action?

Tags: html, forms

Can I use just a single `<input type="submit" value="submit">` but for several form actions ...

Say if I type

```
<form id="form1" action="action1.py" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="name">
</form>
<form id="form2" action="action2.py" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="random">
<form>
```

then I want to use just a single `<input type="submit" value="submit"` or if there is another way to do it? Can anyone please explain me how to do it?

Comment: If there is just one, which should get submitted? Both? Where should the browser go? It can only go to one place from your form.

Comment: I'd tried to make the form enter into two different table but in the same database. So yeah, both should get submitted.. Because im putting both of the form in one page..

Comment: So you can't do two submits at once, but you can use AJAX to submit to two endpoints at once.